# Find and Replace text in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, replace

I am using eclipse IDE.I need to modify thousands of **hbm.xml** file by replacing the text **generate="always"** to **generate="never"**. Please tell  me the easiest way.

Answer (score 8):

Click on the "Search" button, click on the "File Search" tab, set the filename to `hbm.xml`, set the text to `generate="always"` and click on the "Replace" button at the bottom. When it's search for all matches, it'll offer you another dialog to say what to replace it with.

Comment: @PhilipRego: There is for me under the "File search" tab... see http://i.imgur.com/bUM0zh5.png. Will edit to make this clearer, but please be aware that starting your comment with an "order" of "Update this answer" is not exactly the politest way of expressing things.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse search dialogs offer a *global* find and replace in text files.